# Add of std::valarray got different sizes with different operand orders

Tags: c++, valarray

Add of `std::valarray` got different sizes with different operand orders.

Code is as the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::valarray<float> v0{3.f, 0.f};
    std::valarray<float> v1{0.f};
    std::valarray<float> v2 = v0 + v1;
    std::valarray<float> v3 = v1 + v0;
    cout << v2.size() << endl; // 2
    cout << v3.size() << endl; // 1
}
```

Compilers:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0
clang version 9.0.0-2~ubuntu18.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
```

Comment: Attempts to perform arithmetic on two `valarray`s of different sizes exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Fine... But I think preserving the max size and setting the last elements to 0 is more natural.

Comment: @chaosink What matters is what the standard says, not what you'd like it to say. The rationale for why this restriction exists might be performance.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith3

Comment: @bitmask Give me a chance to modify the standard!

Comment: @chaosink Have at it. The way I understand it, everyone is free to suggest papers to the standardization committee. But it usually takes many years until they are incorporated.

Comment: @bitmask This makes me want to implement my own valarray...

Comment: @chaosink if you need that functionality, just wrap the existing valarray and insert appropriate checks in all operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator+()` does not perfom concatenation of two  `std::valarray<float>` objects,

```
std::valarray<float> v2 = v0 + v1;
```

Here, since `v1` is of size 1, it will add the only value in `v1` to both the elements in `v0`, hence size stays 2.

```
std::valarray<float> v2 = v1 + v0;
```

But here, `v1` is of size 1, it will add the first element 3.f to the only element in `v1` and second value of `v0` is ignored.
This is what usually happens, but nevertheless the behaviour of binary operations on two `valarray`s are undefined.